# Why JQuery doesn't trigger added eventlistener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, event-handling

I have recognized, that eventhandler added with `addEventListener` where not influenced by 
`$.trigger`. The special reason for that question is, that I have several self created html elements which implements some logic without using external libraries (only pure js).
Now in my main project I want to use these controls and further there I have external libaries like jQuery.
Now for example I want to trigger the change event (remember...events are added with `element.addEventListener("event", function)`) with `$(element).trigger("change")`.

**Result: nothing happened**

The event only is triggered, when i use code like this:

```
event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("change", true, true);
event.eventName = 'change';
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

On the other side...eventhandler added with jQuery, where also triggered by a custom created event.

Now the magic question: Why??

You can find a little example in the following jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/UYyXv/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an [explanation from the jquery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-jquery-doesn-t-trigger-added-eventlistener#14737000003888849).

> jQuery events are a level higher than the native events. Trigger fakes
>   a jQuery event. If you want to fake a native event you need to call it
>   as you wrote in the question.
>
> Simple answer, don’t use native events.
>
> JΛ̊KE

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just try

```
$(SELECTOR).change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //***DO STUFF HERE***
})
```

Comment: What will you say with this? I don't see why it should explain why an event handler created without jQuery doesn't get triggered by an event fired by jQuery.