# js event listener & jQuery event trigger not being friends

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on converting some of our code base away from jQuery. Up until we got to events, everything was going pretty smoothly.  We have a lot of namespaced code with jQuery, and so for *now* we are not converting the `trigger` function calls away from jQuery. However, we are trying to use js event listeners. Here is problem with custom events:

```
window.addEventListener("testevent", function(e){
 console.log("js fired"); // this doesn't log, but it should!
});

$(window).on("testevent", function(e){
 console.log("jquery listener fired"); // this logs fine, like it should
});

// trigger the custom event with jQuery
$(window).trigger("testevent");
```

If I run the code above in console, I get a log for the jQuery listener, but not the listener. Does anyone know why that is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why JQuery doesn't trigger added eventlistener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232448/why-jquery-doesnt-trigger-added-eventlistener)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery custom events are meant to be used to perform abstractions and simplifications, or to provide more meaning to some event just called *click*.

Furtheremore, these custom events are triggered by jQuery and can be only listened by `jQuery.on`. DOM event listeners will listen DOM events (i.e. ones defined by the W3C's standard).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), `.trigger()` executes any event handlers with the corresponding event. It also says that `.trigger()` only simulates an event and does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

You'll see that they both work if you use `window.dispatchEvent(new Event("testevent"))` to fire a real event.

Answer (score -1):

[Similar question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232448/why-jquery-doesnt-trigger-added-eventlistener)

> jQuery events are a level higher than the native events. Trigger fakes
>   a jQuery event.

Comment: When a SO question is a dupe of another SO question, the dupe should be closed. Answering that it is a dupe with a link to the dupe gets messy.

Comment: How do you close it ?

Comment: If you have sufficient privileges as a SO user, you can add a vote to close by clicking "close" under the question.